# WP7 - access to sample data from code

Tags: windows-phone-7, datasource, expression-blend, sample-data

In expression blend I created a sample data source in visual editor. In case of using a listbox I simply drag the collection there and data is automatically shown.
Now, I am interested to retrieve data from datasource from code behind. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this, I will give you the simplest.  I have a ListPicker that is bascially the same as a ListBox:  Here is my ListPicker markup: [Also here is a link](http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/)

```
  <toolkit:ListPicker  Name="lpDrag" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Loaded="lptest_Loaded"            SelectedIndex="0">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding desc}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  />

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
 lpDrag.ItemsSource = //Whatever your datasource is
```

Comment: Ok, what about if you dont use a control in your page? An empty page and codebehind that needs to access the sample data.

Comment: I guess I dont understand your question.  Are you asking how to retrieve data from a database or something like that?

Comment: In Expression Blend you can create some sample data that can be used in your application. I know how to bind that data to controls but I dont know how can I use the same data in code. I can see the data is located in folder SampleData and can be read in XAML files. Any idea how to call and use it?

Comment: I figured it out. ((SampleDataSource)Application.Current.Resources["SampleDataSource"]).Collection; Thanks for your help, anyway. I marked your response as accepted.